Find Biggest Rectangle Inscribed in Overlap of 3 Equidistant Circles
I'm wondering if there's an optimization or geometric approach to find the maximum area of a rectangle inscribed in the overlap of 3 equidistant circles. The circles have centers $B_1$, $B_2$, $B_3$ respectively, and they all have radius $r$. The circles' centers are all equidistant with distance $d$ (so the centers form an equilateral triangle with a side length of $d$). $d$ is constrained to the interval $0 < d < \sqrt{3}r$ so that there is guaranteed to be an region (call it $R$) in which all three circles overlap. I'm trying to find the biggest rectangle that can be inscribed in this region $R$.
Hopefully this figure is helpful to visualize (the purple region is $R$)
Thanks in advance!

COMMENT.-I give you a hint to solve your problem assuming the rectangle has sides paralles to axis.Take $B_1=(a,0),B_2=(-a,0),B_3=(0,-a)$ you get the circles for your problem with variables $a,r$.
With this choice the point $A$ intersection of second and third circles has positive coordinates $x_0=y_0=\dfrac{-a+\sqrt{2r^2-a^2}}{2}$  which in turn determines the square of vertex $B=(-x_0,y_0),C=(-x_0,-y_0)$ and $D=(x_0,-y_0)$.
Try to prove the square $ABCD$ has maximal area calculating the area $A'B'C'D'$ of red rectangle in the attached figure. Geometric intuition makes it clear that the square has a larger area than the rectangle but it is your job to formally prove this (it is not difficult).

Thanks for the response! This is slightly different than the problem I am asking about; I want the centers of each circle to be equidistant from each other such that they form an equilateral triangle (with your example coordinates, $B_1 = (a, 0), B_2 = (-a, 0), B_3 = (0, \sqrt{{a\over 2}^2 - a^2})$). I was able to use scipy's minimize() method to get, what looks to me, a reasonable answer, but I'd still be curious if there is a geometric proof to show this.

@EthanBuck: My answer follows your requirements but you don't seem to have noticed.

Your answer relies on $B_3 = (0, -a)$, but this would mean $\text{dist}(B_1, B_2) > \text{dist}(B_1, B_3)$. For the center points to be equidistant, $B_3$ would need to be $(0, \sqrt{({a \over 2})^2 - a^2})$. From the original image I linked, if we have point $A$ (the most positive intersection of the second and third circles in the y-direction) and $B$ (the most positive intersection of the first and third circles in the y-direction), projecting $C$ and $D$ down onto the overlapping region would not yield a square as it does in your diagram.
